# tensorflow1.8 page clicks

Tags: javascript

[tensorflow]1.8Version, problem with page clicks:https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/?hl=zh-cn
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOdYi.png)

Answer (score 0):

The page is seems to be broken or under maintenance:

`href="https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/?hl=zh-cn`

should be like

`href="https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/?hl=zh-cn`

[image]